# Oracle - Setting variable to reflect first 3 character of function input value

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a procedure that passes in a string value, which in turn is passed into a function. I need to created a variable of the string passed in to only reflect the first 3 character for use in a like where clause.

Not sure how I would do this, the function below would passes in_mod as say 'abc 123 def' in my select statement I want to effectively take only the first 3 characters passed in so the where clause is evaluted as
And AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE abc||'%';

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPC_OP.sitezone_msm
    (in_site_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id%TYPE
    ,in_zone_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id%TYPE
    ,in_mod AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module%TYPE)

RETURN NUMBER
IS

v_msm NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.weight),0)
    INTO v_msm
    FROM AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS 
    WHERE AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id = in_site_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id = in_zone_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE in_mod||'%'; 
RETURN (v_msm);

END sitezone_msm;
```

Comment: Have you tried "SELECT SUBSTR('ABCDEFG',3,4)"?  You can replace the 3 (starting point) and 4 (how many characters).  You can wrap that around any string, including a function result.

Comment: durbnpoisn - add code as not clear how I can acheive what I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello we can substr function if you know that you have to select only first three chars. I dont have workspace right now but i think this should work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPC_OP.sitezone_msm
    (in_site_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id%TYPE
    ,in_zone_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id%TYPE
    ,in_mod AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module%TYPE)

RETURN NUMBER
IS

v_msm NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.weight),0)
    INTO v_msm
    FROM AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS 
    WHERE AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id = in_site_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id = in_zone_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE SUBSTR(in_mod,1,3)||'%'; 
RETURN (v_msm);

END sitezone_msm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `regexp_substr` to grab the characters at the beginning of the string before the first space.  In case the rule really is the characters before the space, not just the first three (in case that could be a variable number of characters).  Depends on your data.

```
AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE regexp_substr(in_mod, '^([^ ]*) ', 1, 1, null, 1)  ||'%';
```

Or if you prefer `regexp_replace`:

```
AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE regexp_replace(in_mod, '^([^ ]*) (.*)', '\1')  ||'%';
```

Comment: Thanks for all feedback its been a few years since I've carried out any PL/SQL - I have tried above suggestions and function is now returning expected values. Thanks for all your help